# Thrift include: Type has not been defined

Tags: thrift

I have a two thrift files: `common.thrift`, `proto.thrift`

content:

**common.thrift**

```
namespace java ru.domain.myserv.common

struct MyStruct {
    1: i32 val
}

service MyServ {
    1: MyStruct myStruct,
    2: i32 val
}
```

**proto.thrift**

```
include "common.thrift"

namespace java ru.domain.myserv.proto

typedef ru.domain.myserv.common.MyServ MyServ

struct ProtoServ {
    1: MyServ myServ
}
```

Next, I run the thrift generator:

`thrift -r -out ../java --gen java proto.thrift`

And I see an errors in console:

`[ERROR:/path/proto.thrift:8] (last token was 'ru.domain.myserv.common.MyServ')
Type "ru.domain.myserv.common.MyServ" has not been defined.`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh my God.

I had to specify

`typedef common.MyServ MyServ`

instead of

`typedef ru.domain.myserv.common.MyServ MyServ`

But for what then `namesapace` is necessary?

Comment: The `namespace` is used for code generation. Note that you can have multiple namespaces, one per target language. Plus of course the asterisk form `namespace  *  myapi.myapp.com`. So re IDL it would become slightly complicated using `namespace` for references (which one?) - and much too verbose.